# cakephp Error: ItemsController could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I am very new to cakephp.

I have my project named "catalog"

i'm working with xampp and cakephp version 2.3.7

i have created controller app/Controller/ItemsController.php

```
class ItemsController extends AppController{

public function index(){

    $this->set('color', 'blue');
}}
```

i have created View/Items/index.ctp

```
<?php echo $color  ?>
```

when i'm trying to access in the browser "catalog/"

et working fine i have a start page :
Release Notes for CakePHP 2.5.3. ....
............

but when im trying to reach my controller like : "catalog/items"
**i have an error**

```
Missing Controller
Error: ItemsController could not be found.

Error: Create the class ItemsController below in file:         app\Controller\ItemsController.php

<?php
class ItemsController extends AppController {

}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create     app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp

Stack Trace
APP\webroot\index.php line 108 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

please somebody help me

Comment: Have u properly declare the items controller in app/controller??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i made a mistake
i have been created two folders 
one with xampp and other with netbeans